# Como pegar valor do Form - Java - Swing

Tags: java, swing

Criei um formulário no `Java` com interface `Swing`, neste tem um campo `textfield` **Texto** e um botão **Enviar**, no código do botão preciso atribuir o valor `informado` no `textfield` a um variável do tipo `String`, qual a função para isto ?

Comment: Poste seu código para darmos uma olhada.

Comment: `String str = textField.getText();` se entendi bem, creio que isso já resolva.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Qual o motivo do ```(String)```, é alguma conversão de dados ?

Comment: Corrigi, conforme a [**documentação do java**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) neste caso não precisa fazer o cast, ele já traz direto como string.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Vou testar assim que possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Não tinha visto os comentários, foi mal.

O seguinte código deve funcionar:

`String s = textField.getText()`

E a partir daí tu trata `s` como for necessário.

Caso surjam mais dúvidas a respeito do `TextField`, segue a documentação:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html

Abraço

Comment: Sem problemas. Não respondi diretamente porque quis esperar o OP manifestar se o problema era simples assim mesmo. De qualquer forma, sua resposta é válida :)

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, ficou assim: o objeto -  ```JTextField texto = new JTextField();``` a variável - ```String textoaux = texto.getText();```, obrigado.